# Python Pandas - Evaluating math expressions in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been trying to evaluate math expressions in the Resolution and o_resolution columns. I have used regex to change `x` into `*` and have used the eval function to try to evaluate the expressions in the column but nothing is happening. Any suggestions?

```
colRes = df [['resolution', 'o_resolution']]

colRes = df[['resolution', 'o_resolution']].replace('x','*',regex=True)
colRes = df[['resolution', 'o_resolution']].apply(lambda x:eval('x'))
```

[Resolution Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASgpy.png)

[o_resolution Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuWyl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.eval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.eval.html) in [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) after replace:

```
d = {'resolution':['10x2','8x9','1x8'], 'o_resolution':['10x4','10x40','10x500']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)


colRes = df [['resolution', 'o_resolution']].replace('x','*',regex=True).applymap(pd.eval)
print (colRes)
  resolution o_resolution
0         20           40
1         72          400
2          8         5000
```

Your solution is possible with `x` instead `'x'`, but not [recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice):

```
colRes = df[['resolution', 'o_resolution']].replace('x','*',regex=True).applymap(lambda x:eval(x))
```